# Node.js Object Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const db = require("quick.db")

exports.ping = async function(client) {
    const botid = await db.fetch(`wl_${client.id}`)   
    if(!botid) return "Merhaba. Bu komutu kullanamazsınız. Çünkü beyaz listemizde değilsiniz. Beyaz listemizde olabilmek için CodHure sunucumuzda belirli bir davete ulaşıp modülümüze erişim sağlamalısınız. Yoksa bu modülü kullanamazsınız."

}
```

The code returns as "[Object promise]". How can I fix?

Comment: Which part of the code? currently, you just have a function but you do not call it.

Comment: Do you even need `async/await` here? Try removing it

Comment: I don't know much, but I will try to explain.
This is a module file. My purpose for this code is to find out if the bot is whitelisted. If the bot is not in the white list, this command will be executed:
```if(!botid) return "Merhaba. Bu komutu kullanamazsınız. Çünkü beyaz listemizde değilsiniz. Beyaz listemizde olabilmek için CodHure sunucumuzda belirli bir davete ulaşıp modülümüze erişim sağlamalısınız. Yoksa bu modülü kullanamazsınız."
```

Comment: You cannot fix it. In the code where you are calling the function, you need to *wait* for the promise.

Comment: I removed `async/await` but this time it returns "undefined".

Comment: @TheVagus you're exporting a `promise`, so the way you'd call this somewhere else would be to call it as such: `ping({...}).then(result => {...})`... when you use `async` keyword in front of a function it turns it into a `promise`

Comment: Thank you @goto1, code is working.

Comment: @AshishModi how would that change anything? `db.fetch` returns a Promise, so no matter if the OP is using await/async or not, the `ping` function has to either return a Promise or utilize a callback (if the caller wants to get a return value based on the `fetch` result), so removing await/async would not change the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are export an async function, so the return value will be Promise. Use your module like this

```
//if you are using your module in none async function
yourModuleName.ping(client)
    .then(result => {
          ...
    })
    .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
    });

//if you are using your module in async function 
try{
    const result = await yourModuleName.ping(client);
    ...
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: but this is not following async/await. Because await will resolve the promise, which is cleaner and more related to question. You are using es6 syntax when the question is in es7.

Comment: I guess the questioner is using the module in none async function, but your tip is right. @PHPNoob